# Use for loop to select dom in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, dom

it's frustrating that we can't select JSON elements (or really any elements) using a similar code like this:

```
//An JSON object is parsed into Response beforehand
for(var count = 1; count <= Response.objCount; count ++) {
  console.log(Response.obj+count.content);
}
```

In the code, I want to output a JSON object like this:

```
{ "objCount" : 2 ,
  "obj1" : { "result" : true ,
             "content" : "blah blah 1" } ,
  "obj2" : { "result" : true ,
             "content" : "blah blah 2" } }
```

But no, we can't use variable as whole or part of an identifier in Javascript..
So, any suggestions on how to handle such JSON objects when I want to output each and every object?

Thank you!

Comment: The only thing confusing about this question is that it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the DOM.

Comment: That's right. My bad, I am editing the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "Response" is your structure, then you can indeed do what you ask:

```
for(var key in Response) {
  console.log(Response[key].content);
}
```

You can't loop on "length" because "Response" is not an array, and plain objects don't have a "length" property.

Now, one problem is that you can't be sure that you'll get the components out in any particular order. That is, the loop above may give you "obj2" before you get "obj1".  You could address that problem in a couple of ways. First, you could re-think your data structure and store it as an array.  Alternatively, you could fetch the keys and sort them, and then iterate through the sorted array of property names.

```
var keys = Object.keys(Response);
keys.sort(function(key1, key2) {
  // comparison ...
});
for (var count = 0; count < keys.length; ++count)
  console.log(Response[keys[count]].content);
```

The `Object.keys()` function only works in newer browsers, but you can do a similar trick with a `for ... in` loop to pull out the property names.

*edit* — with your updated structure that includes an explicit property of your own for the length, you can use a plain `for` loop:

```
for (var count = 1; count <= Response.objCount; ++count)
  console.log(Response["obj" + count].content);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the "length" issue. I didn't include my entire code, my mistake on missing that part. The question is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets to access the property using the property name as a string:

```
Response["obj" + count].content
```

Comment: @TheJinStudio: Then you didn't include all of the details. What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What error do you get?

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment. It does work actually. Thank you! voted up!